# Server Error in '/' Application. ASPNETDB.MDF ... ON PRODUCTION SERVER

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, publishing-site

I m getting the following error when i upload my site to Production Server using Database in App_Data ASPNETDB.MDF

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this
>   application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed
>   remotely (for security reasons). It
>   could, however, be viewed by browsers
>   running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please
>   create a  tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

web.config:

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's 
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I M CONFUSED WHY THIS ERROR OCCURED ?? AND HIW TO FIX THIS TO DISPLAY WEBSITE ...

Comment: Have you bothered to follow the instructions it's giving you? Or tried accessing the site directly from the server so you can see more error details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at scottgu's article - [Recipe: Deploying a SQL Database to a Remote Hosting Environment (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/22/recipe-deploying-a-sql-database-to-a-remote-hosting-environment-part-1.aspx) and an article from Scott Mitchell - [Deploying a Local Database to a Remote Web Host](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306172456/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050907-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For quick troubleshooting only:
Just follow what it was asking...
open your web.config file and change the  mode attribute to Off temporarily.  I am assuming you have it redirect to something else at the moment that prevents you from seeing the real error.

In the long run, it's a good practice to capture and log errors into some sort of persistence media (db, log file, etc.) and troubleshoot from those.  Perhaps thru a custom admin web interface to look at the errors or simply ftping the log files back to your machine and investigate it locally.